# I don't agree that it's easy to categorize user's problems as math problems

Tags: discussion

I note [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268043/finding-double-cosets-of-a-group) is going to close by the *Mathematic* question(not a *Mathematica*). I think it is a function of *Mathematica* to try or practice with *MMA* when learning *Mathematic*. We can't simply categorize this need as a purely mathematical problem and then ask to close it.

In this post, we can know the user is indeed trying to use *MMA* to solve math problems:

> [image]

And he is a new user with only 1 score. I think it's cruel to close the post directly.

Last but no least, *MMA* programming is highly related to mathematical problems. We cannot ignore this, for example, all problems tagged on *differential equations* are essentially mathematical problems, but we do accept it.

Comment: I somehow agree with @Yode and voted to keep this question open. It is, after all, a direct question about *Wolfram Mathematica*. Not a very good one though, as it does not show due diligence, and it's hard to argue that this is a question anybody would want to curate for posterity.

Comment: @rhermans I agree with you that the problem doesn't show user diligence, but don't close it as a math problem. This is after all different. I'm just saying it's not a math problem

Comment: I think I'd characterize the issue differently. The question is not even appropriate for math.SE, which I think is easy to see. I can't explain the votes, though. They seem mistakes but not cruelty. I think math.SE would likely reject the migration. -- Characterizing something as a "math problem" is not the same as saying it belongs on math.SE, though it seems that's what you meant. We have lots of mathematics-problem tags, not just diff. eq. And the first book on Mathematica was called *Mathematica: A System for Doing Mathematics by Computer*.